# MS Access VBA - extract listbox value on a form (using form name.)

Tags: vba, forms, object, ms-access, listbox

This seemed to be working but just stopped and I'm not sure what I changed to cause this.

I have a listbox on a form. (a single select listbox).

To extract the value, I can do `me.listboxName.Column(0)` and that works perfectly.

However, that's not the code I want to use. (as I will reference it from another form )

```
Form_myformName.listboxName.Column(0)
```

is what I had, and it worked and now it's stopped. It still works for similar code on other forms, so I'm not sure what's happened.

If I type in `me.name`, it tells me correctly that my form name is "myFormName". 
If I type in `Form_myFormName`., it prompts me with the name of my list box so I know I have the names correct. However, if I try to extract the value using:

```
 Form_myformName.listboxName.Column(0)
```

it gives me a value of `Null`, despite the listbox having a selected value. (which I can sucessfully extract by using me.listboxname etc)

hopefully that makes sense. anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
Forms("myformname").listboxName.Column(0)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I get this message:

Run- Time error '2450' - Database cannot find the referenced form 'myformname' .  It's as if the code cannot extract from the form. (yet when I pull out the myFormname.name or even me.listboxname.name, it sees the actual objects...